# Constructor getting invoked after a method

Tags: php

Upon invoking `tryTest()`, the output is

> Test thisJo

Why is 'Test this' printing first and then Jo. Looks like the constructor is being invoked after the method is invoked. Also the text should print Mary since I am assigning the value in the constructor. But it echoes Jo.

```
<?php
class cityme {
    public $nm = "Jo";
    public $state = null;
    public $country = null;

    function _construct($name, $state, $country) {
        // set the name
        $this->nm = $name;
        echo $this->nm; // this echoes after the printout function is called.. and the value is Jo... 
        // set the state
        $this->state = $state;
        // set the country
        $this->country = $country;
    }


    /**
     * Print the info
     */
    public function printout()  {

        if($this->nm == null)  {
            echo "it worked";//does not echo
        }
        echo "Test this";//echoes first... 
        echo $this->nm;
        echo $this->state;
        echo $this->country;
    }
}

function tryTest() {
    $myCity = new cityme("Mary", "Charlotte", "US");
    $myCity->printout();
}
?>
```

Comment: `__construct` has 2 underscores

Comment: This is my code. And yes i was using only 1 underscore. Thanks for the correction. Completely new to php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor is missing an underscore. It should be:

```
function __construct($name, $state, $country) {
```